# how to disable run as , debug as options in context menu in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I am working on a C/C++ plugin in Eclipse. Based on the project type I want to disable the "Run as" and "Debug as" options from the project context menu.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could check and see if you need the "`org.eclipse.debug.ui`" and "`org.eclipse.debug.core`" plugins in your plugin.

See [this thread](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t112286.html#92243897):

I found the cause:
Eclipse 3.4 adds "`org.eclipse.debug.ui`" and "`org.eclipse.debug.core`" when clicking the "`Add Reguired Plugins`" in the product editor.
Eclipse 3.3 didn't do this, so I for sure the plugin dependency is the cause in the new version. These plugins contribute somehow to the EMF popup menu in the screen shot.
I removed both and my product continues to function correctly

Comment: i have implemented my own RUN Configuration and Debug Configuration which will supports the options based on the project selection;